# Проблема с ЧПУ в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, чпу

Всем доброго времени суток! Знаю что тема уже изъезженная, но всё-равно возникла проблема:
пытаюсь настроить ЧПУ, необходимо чтобы по адресу site.ru/articles/url отображалось содержимое страницы site.ru/articles.html?site=sit.ru&url=url. Делаю так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^articles/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)? articles.html?site=site.ru&url=$1 [L]
```

Но при переходе по адресу site.ru/articles/url меня редиректит на site.ru/articles.html?site=sit.ru&url=url, а нужно чтобы адрес оставался.

Подскажите, как решить вопрос? Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Cкопировал ваш код — у меня всё работает нормально. Вероятно, проблема либо в других правилах в этом файле, либо в других файлах .htaccess, например, в папке articles (если она есть).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так

```
RewriteRule ^articles/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)? articles.html?site=site.ru&url=$1 [L,QSA]
```